# How to request User to turn DND mode in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to request user to turn on DND mode suppose in form of a dialog box, how can i do that?
This code is not working.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        showDNDDialog()

    }

    fun showDNDDialog() {

        val nAlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        nAlertDialog.setTitle("Request")
        nAlertDialog.setMessage("Please turn on DND mode for better functioning")
        nAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok") { dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int ->

            val mNotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE)
            }
    
            dialog?.dismiss()

        }
        nAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int ->
            dialog?.dismiss()
        }
        nAlertDialog.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean Don't desturb ?

Comment: Yes, DND - Do not disturb